# .Net Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-authentication

I'm developing a website in mvc2, and i'm using the .net Authentication. How can i do to change my login authorization to use email and password.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inside your controller action which emits the authentication cookie just check if the mail matches the password and use the email as username for the authentication cookie:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string email, string password)
{
    // TODO: query your membership provider and verify if the given email
    // matches the password and if they match emit the authentication cookie
    // using the email as username

}
```